# how to add img src (with php script) in meta tag html

Tags: php, html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

I Have a litle bit problem with meta tag image script.

I already try like this :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "<img src='/img/$image'>"; ?>" />
```

is that possible ? 
thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. What does your HTML source reveal?

Comment: You don't put `<img src` in that field. Just use your image URL. From http://ogp.me/: "_og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph._"

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way.

What you are trying to output, with your `<?php echo "<img src='...'>"; ?>` is a full HTML tag.

But, you output this string inside the **value** of an **attribute** (namely, attribute `content`) of a **tag** (`<meta>`).

This value must be a string, and I believe that you simply need to print there the absolute URL of the image (not the full `<img>` tag!).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use image tag there. Instead, you should use

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/img/$image"; ?>" />
```